# How do I generalize small numbers on an Excel map?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am utilizing the map feature on Excel to create a county-level map for my state that includes visit counts for each county. For any counts less than 5, I want to display them as "<5" to avoid small numbers. However, the map does not seem to let me add any text at all that is not a number. If I try to add anything other than a number, the map changes it to "0".

I tried changing the cell format to Text, Special, and Custom but none of that helped. I have tried creating columns that are entirely text-based and they will not show up on the map at all. I am unable to edit individual data labels for those specific numbers.

Comment: Can you show us what your data look like? (And what about a helper column?)

Comment: Look at this screenshot it might help, **[here](https://imgur.com/gallery/w1GgapI)** you need to create a helper column like i did and use that column in map chart then it would display those which are less than `<5` The formula i have used works with `MS365` --> `=IF(B2:B51<5,"<5",TEXT(B2:B51,"@"))` and if you dont have any of these then simply use `=IF(B2<5,"<5",TEXT(B2,"@"))` . Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @Dominique a helper column was what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As commented above this should work for your requirement.

[image]

---

- Create a `Helper/Auxiliary` column beside the `Visits` columns
- Enter the following formula in the adjacent column

---

```
=IF(B2:B51<5,"<5",B2:B51)
```

---

- Now just select the `Country` column (in example here its `States`, and the `helper column`) and from `Insert` Tab click on `Maps` and `Filled Maps`.
- Once done right click on the `Map` and `Add Data Labels`.

This would show those visits less than `<5` as well as one more than `5`

---